# Disable or hide select option if keyword is present in other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I want to hide or disable a select option if a keyword is present in an element higher up the page. Here's some example HTML:

```
<div>

    <div id="divID">The word EXAMPLE is in this sentence.</div>

    <select id="optionList" name="optionList">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
        <option value="1">First option</option>
        <option value="2">Second option</option>
        <option value="3">Third option</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

So the psuedo-code would go something like this:

IF the word "example" is present in the div with ID "divID"...

THEN make select option "Third Option" hidden (or inactive, or otherwise not an option for the user).

OTHERWISE leave all the select options alone.

I imagine this is pretty basic stuff for anyone who knows what they're doing, which I clearly do not.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Using `jquery` plus `regular expressions`, following should be a basic sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (/EXAMPLE/.test($('#divID').text()))
        $('option[value="3"]').hide();
});
```

Comment: can't use `hide()` or `display:none` on an `<option>` ... not supported cross browser ...notably IE and I think Safari also. remove or disable are choices

Answer (score 0):

check this js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/pe1yvucj/
notice this line

```
$("option[value='3']").attr('disabled','disabled')
```

to make it enabled again

```
$("option[value='3']").removeAttr('disabled')
```